# How to format clipboard text to paste as hyperlink?

Tags: hyperlink, autohotkey

How can I generate a rich text hyperlink on my clipboard using something like autohotkey?

Basically I want to create a paste as hyperlink shortcut. Currently I highlight some text and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> which sends <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> (create hyperlink hotkey in many programs), then sends <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste in my location, and finally enter to confirm.

This works well enough but I was hoping to make it general enough to work anywhere that supports rich text, even if it doesn't have a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> shortcut available.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Most programs automatically convert a URL to a hyperlink as soon as you enter it and press [Enter].

Comment: @RobertIlbrink still not general enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple code:

In this example I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste a hyperlink in your format:

```
^+v::
Send, ^k %Clipboard% {Enter}
Return
```

or...

```
^+v::
StringReplace, ClipBoard, ClipBoard, http://  ; strip  http://
StringReplace, ClipBoard, ClipBoard, https://  ; strip  http://
Send, <a href="http://%ClipBoard%">%ClipBoard%</a>
Return
```

Comment: @hoytdj Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you replace https with http when you generate the link? Wouldn't that lead to a broken link in some cases?

Comment: Caleb, You are right. An analysis of the http string and a if-then-else, would be better.